# Change multiple SSRS data driven subscriptions for changing file shares

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have dozens of data driven subscriptions that we run manually at the beginning of the month that use file share delivery. They point to a certain server's shared drive.

That server is going away, so we need to either manually change the data driven sql that dynamically creates a path/filename for the dozens of subscriptions,

or we were hoping we could run an update statement or something? Below is kind of what we want to change. All instances of ATLACT02 to something else.

!!!!!!!!!!

Select 'Pro Bono Section ' + RTRIM(SECT_CODE) + ' ' + RTRIM(@PERIOD) AS 'FILE_NAME',

'\ATLACT02\Crystal Reports\Reports\Section\'+RTRIM(SECT_CODE) +'\'+ RTRIM(@PERIOD) AS 'PATH',

RTRIM(SECT_CODE)  AS SECT,

RTRIM(@PERIODEND) AS PERIODEND,

RTRIM(@PERIODBEGIN) AS PERIODBEGIN

From _HBL_SECT SECT

Where SECT.INACTIVE = 'N' AND (SECT_CODE BETWEEN '100' AND '699')

AND SECT_CODE NOT IN ('101','201','301','401','501','601')

Comment: From what I'm reading online, it looks like SSRS subscriptions are actually set up behind the scenes as SQL Server Agent jobs, and thus can be entered and altered directly through SSMS - if you can locate the jobs in the SSMS, you could potentially do a find and replace operation on the jobs: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/

Answer (score 1):

in your reporting services database

```
  select * from Subscriptions where ExtensionSettings like '%ATLACT02%'
```

You can use some fancy TSQL to update the XML in that field or simply use the REPLACE

```
UPDATE Subscription 
SET ExtensionSettings = REPLACE(ExtensionSettings,'ATLACT02','NewServerName')
WHERE ExtensionSettings like '%ATLACT02%'
```

Obviously a bit of testing would be pretty useful before attempting to change all your datadriven subscriptions

Comment: The ExtensionSettings column doesn't really have much... I think because we use a lot of data driven subscriptions with a sql that generates a custom path. But you steered us in the right direction and I noticed the DataSettings column has the custom query. Thanks for the help. We'll see if we can do updates.